# Get SSL for virtualhosts on MacOS (Apache)

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4

I have a Mac OS Big Sur host which is running Apache. I have configured several virtual hosts. Now I want to enable SSL so I could access a local site using https://example.local.

I'm looking at this issue for more than three hours now and not one tutorial seems to work.

[This](https://www.jobsity.com/blog/apache-ssl-mac-osx) tutorial for example:
Step two gives the following error:

```
unable to load Private Key
4781444780:error:09FFF06C:PEM routines:CRYPTO_internal:no start line:/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-56.60.2/libressl-2.8/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:684:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

server.key is in the directory though.

I also tried [this tutorial using Certbot](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-bigsur-apache-ssl). But Certbot needs a publicly accessible domain, my local virtual host is of course not public.

Another command I tried and got from [here](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/) is:

```
openssl req -x509 -out localhost.crt -keyout localhost.key \
  -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 \
  -subj '/CN=example.local' -extensions EXT -config <( \
   printf "[dn]\nCN=example.local\n[req]\ndistinguished_name = dn\n[EXT]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:example.local\nkeyUsage=digitalSignature\nextendedKeyUsage=serverAuth")
```

Than I configured my vhost file like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/Niel/Sites/example/"
    ServerName example.local

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/Users/niel/.config/letsencrypt/localhost.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/Users/niel/.config/letsencrypt/localhost.key"

    <Directory "/Users/Niel/Sites/example/">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This gives the following error in `/var/log/apache2/error_log`:

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Tue Dec 29 00:15:13.939507 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 68986] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'zip.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/zip.so (dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/zip.so, 9): image not found), /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/zip.so.so (dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/zip.so.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0
[Tue Dec 29 00:15:14.145551 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 68986] AH00163: Apache/2.4.46 (Unix) LibreSSL/2.8.3 PHP/7.3.24-(to be removed in future macOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Dec 29 00:15:14.145632 2020] [core:notice] [pid 68986] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Tue Dec 29 00:19:41.205429 2020] [authz_core:error] [pid 69057] [client 127.0.0.1:58915] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /Users/Niel/Websites
```

Anyway, I tried a thousand of things but none worked. How can I get SSL on my virtual hosts using Apache on MacOS?

Comment: Apart from this question being off topic: why don't you simply use the certificate that comes with Apache? You need to tell your browser to trust it anyway, if it is the shipped certificate or one you created yourself.

Comment: Second, your log file does not show any problem with your certificate, it only shows a permission error. And the file system path does not match the config file paths. Most probably you have another part of your config that is used instead and that you haven't shown.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Could you elaborate on your first comment please? Where can I find that Apache certificate and how to add it to my virtual hosts?